# How to install SAGA 2.1 with QGIS dufour on Windows?

Tags: qgis, windows, saga, qgis-2

I need that someone tell me how i can install saga in qgis 2.0 correctly in windows, because if I install QGIS 2.0 and when I try to use SAGA I get this

Missing dependency.This algorithm cannot be run :-( 
This algorithm requires SAGA to be run.Unfortunately, it seems that SAGA is not installed in your system, or it is not correctly configured to be used from QGIS

Comment: On Windows, the OSGeo4W installer is a safe bet. It includes SAGA. I've also had feedback that the new stand-alone installer provides SAGA as well (http://anitagraser.com/2013/10/02/add-polygon-attributes-to-points-vs-join-attributes-by-location/).

Comment: I have OSGeo4W installed, I installed the last stand-alone verison of QGis 2.0 and still get this dependency problem

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Our protocols can take a little getting used to but you have made a comment in the area reserved for a direct Answer to this Question.

Comment: I have same problem on win 64 with osgeo QGIS (now 2.2 but also 2.0). I triple checked the path "SAGA folder" is C:\OSGeo4W\apps\saga and saga_cmd.exe with all other files are there. Whatewer I do I get Missing dependency.

Answer (score 5):

Download SAGA from http://sourceforge.net/projects/saga-gis/files/

Under processing choose options and configuration. There choose SAGA and make sure the path points to the directory to which you installed saga.

Comment: I triple checked the path "SAGA folder" is C:\OSGeo4W\apps\saga and saga_cmd.exe with all other files are there. Whatewer I do I get Missing dependency. (win 64 with osgeo64 QGIS (now 2.2 but also 2.0))

Comment: Actually I just chacked and the same problem is with GRASS tools and Orfeo Toolbox. I can see all the tools but when I try to run it it is Missing dependency.

Comment: Miro: better ask a new question for QGIS 2.2. Make sure you mention which version of the processing plugin you use.

Comment: I did fresh install on my second computer and everything works good. That brings me to idea it must be conflict of some leftovers of previous QGIS versions or problem with using both 32 and 64 versions. I will try to uninstall and clean my c:\OSGeo4W64 and c:\users\user\.qgis2 to see if it helps.

Comment: Argh. It runs on fresh install but I have only restarted computer few times and it is not working anymore. I didn't do any changes. It worked right after install and now id doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a solution so much as a workaround, but:

I just ran the operation in the SAGA GUI. It wasn't that hard to figure out how to do the basic stuff in SAGA, then save the .shp file (or whatever format) and reload that back into QGIS.